# Versioning server responses

Tags: android, json, protocol-buffers

I am trying to wrap my head around this versioning issue, and I would like to ask you for some help:

Assume these requests are made in JSON:

- Say your server, for endpoint /X, returns a message with fields A and B
- On your Android client app version 1, you expect to get fields A and B when you get a response from /X

Along the line, you decide that on your Android client app version 2, you will no longer need field B

Since Android client app version 1 is still present for some users, you cannot take field B from the response yet, which will clutter the response for newer android clients with legacy fields

---

What would be a good approach to version these responses?

- Handle versioning in the server, and send the proper response according to the android client version (or according to the requested version of the schema that the client requests)
- Does protobuf versioning help in this case? Because it seems that we would always have to send the legacy B parameter for newer responses
- Any other suggestions?

Comment: Had similar concern for one of my app. I would go for first one "Handle versioning in the server, and send the proper response according to the android client version (or according to the requested version of the schema that the client requests)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Handle versioning in the server, and send the proper response
>   according to the android client version (or according to the requested
>   version of the schema that the client requests)

I'd handle the versioning at the server. You don't know what other changes future versions will introduce.

> Does protobuf versioning help in this case?

Well, kinda. If a client is aware of parameter A and not B, he'll be able to read A without a problem. A client that's aware of both will be able to read both. In either case, the client's behavior will be correct and the only problem is a redundant parameter (which might hurt performance, but not correctness).

> Any other suggestions?

Have the server distinguish version #1 from version #2 and send the appropriate parameters. You can even set a separate API for each API version. So V1 clients will connect to www.myapi.com/api/apiv1 while V2 will connect to www.myapi.com/api/apiv2 or something similar.